# can't create new AWS java web project

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, amazon-web-services

I'm using Eclipse 4.2.1 
under OSX 10.8.2.

In Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs,
I have Java SE 6 installed.

I installed Amazon AWS SDK from the Eclipse Marketplace.

I'm trying to start a new AWS Java Web Project
and I get the following errors:

```
Unable to create new AWS Java web project.
One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
Dynamic Web Module 2.5 require Java 1.5 or newer.
```

but I have Java SE 1.6! Why?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Eclipse for Java EE instead of Eclipse generic and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Windows 8.1 Pro.  I tried a bunch of things, but I wasn't able to successfully deploy anything to AWS ElasticBeanstalk until I removed all existing versions of Java and then installed Java EE 7u45 win32 (previously was JEE 8, both 32 & 64 bit).

But here is what I did entirely:

- Deleted existing workspace and created a new one.
- Make sure that your AWS Toolkit Preferences are setup correctly: *Window -> Preferences -> AWS Toolkit*
- Removed all existing versions of java.
- Downloaded and installed Java EE 7u45 win32.
- Made sure that my System Path and JAVA_HOME variables were set properly:  *Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environmental Variables*

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

I installed Eclipse 4.3.2, then added AWS on top and I get the same error. Same with running Eclipse on Java 1.7.0_51 or Java 8 (b132).

I also get an error dialog saying "X does not exist" where X is my new project name. X was created but there is only a .project file and one file in .settings.

My error log contains:

```
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [X does not exist]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.newNotPresentException(JavaElement.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getPerProjectInfoCheckExistence(JavaModelManager.java:2309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getPerProjectInfo(JavaProject.java:1908)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:1930)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.elasticbeanstalk.webproject.CreateNewAwsJavaWebProjectRunnable.findSdkClasspathEntry(CreateNewAwsJavaWebProjectRunnable.java:219)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.elasticbeanstalk.webproject.CreateNewAwsJavaWebProjectRunnable.run(CreateNewAwsJavaWebProjectRunnable.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)

org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.operation.FacetProjectCreationOperation.execute(FacetProjectCreationOperation.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.elasticbeanstalk.webproject.CreateNewAwsJavaWebProjectRunnable.run(CreateNewAwsJavaWebProjectRunnable.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$1.run(FacetedProject.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modify(FacetedProject.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.operation.FacetProjectCreationOperation.execute(FacetProjectCreationOperation.java:83)
    ... 10 more
```

Dynamic Web Module 2.5 requires Java 1.5 or newer.

Arg,